# Cordova camera plugin displays a black screen when the user denies access to the camera in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, camera

I'm making use of the cordova camera plugin in my App (which is supported only for iOS now) and the app uses both the camera and the photo library to select photos. There is an issue with how the plugin responds when ever the user denies access to the device camera. Check out the screen shot below when the user denies access to the camera:

[image]

But when the access is denied for photo library I get the following message displayed:

[image]

I investigated the plugin code and found that they are not checking for the permission but instead checking only if the device has a camera or not, I could make a change to the plugin code to check for the access permission as well but that would be my last resort.

Is there a way of knowing whether the user has accepted or denied access to the camera/photo library before we call the plugin?

I'm making use of ionic version 1.2.13 and cordova version 4.1.3. I have tested this out on iPhone 6/iOS 8.1 and iPad Air2/iOS 8.1

Comment: file an issue on the cordova JIRA page if you think it isn't working as expected

Comment: We are experiencing this as well

Comment: I have filled in a bug -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8658

Answer (score 1):

I filed a PR to address this (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/49), which has been merged into the Cordova Camera plugin. I don't believe they've pushed a release containing this fix to npm, yet, but if you install it directly from github, you should be able to pick it up.

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera`
```